# Mkdocs material Horizontal menu not working

Tags: mkdocs

i'm trying to get the horizontal menu to work but no luck.
here is my .yml file

```
site_name: Documentation

nav:
- Unity 3D :
    - Introduction : Unity3D/SplinePlus/Introduction.md

- Unreal Engine :
    - Introduction : Unity3D/SplinePlus/Introduction.md

theme :
  name: 'material'
extra:
  feature:
    tabs: true
```

the feature does not seam to be enabled,
am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution.
seems like i should do something like this instead of what i have been doing.

```
theme :
  name: 'material'
  feature:
    tabs: true
```